# I'm having an issue with event scheduling in the ECA module in Drupal 9

Tags: events, drupal, conditional-statements, action

I'm having an issue with event scheduling in the ECA module in Drupal 9. My task is to delay email sending by 30 minutes, and I'm using the 'enqueue a task with a delay' action. Below is my ECA model.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vPdj.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CtYz6.png)[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WIHIU.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUPfW.png)